# Defining a new font-face isn't working properly

Tags: css

I'm trying to get a new font I've installed in my folders to work, and for some reason I can't figure out it isin't.
Here's my code:

```
@font-face{
   font-family: "qontra";
   src: url("../fonts/Qontra.otf") format("opentext");

}
h1 {
   margin-top:0;
    font-family: 'qontra';
}
```

Here's the file path:
mywebsite\fonts

Comment: What folder is this CSS in?

Comment: "opentext" seems to be an undefined format. See [Font reference: src descriptor](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-fonts-3/#src-desc). Maybe you want "opentype"?